# Excel VBA Userform QueryClose: Cancel not working

Tags: vba, excel

I've written the code below so that it will check if a process has been completed or not before closing the form. This userform is used as a scoresheet that will make `range("A6")` green to signify a pass, or `range("B6")` red to signify a fail as the final step of the sub, before unloading the form.

From what I've checked online so far, it should be working. While debugging, the macro gets all the way to where it says Cancel = True, reads over the line, but the form closes anyway.

Why isn't the cancel registering even when it reads over the line?

```
Private Sub Userform_queryclose(CloseMode As Integer, Cancel As Integer)
Dim wbScoreCard As Workbook
Dim wsScoreCard As Worksheet
Dim MSG As String
Set wbScoreCard = Workbooks(NameBox.Value)
Set wsScoreCard = wbScoreCard.Worksheets(Format(Date, "MM.dd.yy") & " " & CallType.Caption)
If Err.Number = 0 Then
    If wsScoreCard.Range("A6").Interior.Color <> vbGreen Then
        If wsScoreCard.Range("B6").Interior.Color <> vbRed Then
            Beep
            MSG = MsgBox("This scorecard is not complete! If you close it now, this scorecard will not be saved. Continue?", vbYesNo, "Warning - Scorecard Incomplete")
            If MSG = vbYes Then
                wbScoreCard.Close savechanges:=False
                Exit Sub
            Else
                Cancel = True
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why is `Cancel` an integer when you end up setting it to true (1)? What's `Cancel` doing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Couple of things:

- You're not shutting off error handling, so the `Err.Number = 0` check has no effect; if there's a runtime error, execution jumps straight out of the procedure anyway.
- `MSG` should be a `vbMsgBoxResult`, not a `String`. Your code only works because of implicit type conversions from the underlying `Integer` value to the `String` type you're forcing it into.
- Unless you didn't post your entire code, `Exit Sub` is redundant in both branches.
- The problem can be reproduced with simpler code:

  ```
  Private Sub Userform_queryclose(CloseMode As Integer, Cancel As Integer)
      Cancel = True
  End Sub
  ```

The problem is that you made up that signature or somehow typed it up from memory. This is the signature for the `QueryClose` handler:

> ```
> Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
> ```

**Notice the ordering of parameters**.

You'll get the expected behavior by setting your `CloseMode` to `True` instead of `Cancel`... but a better fix would be to put the parameters in the correct order.

Event handlers don't really care about parameter names: it's about types and order. Since both parameters are `Integer`, it's down to ordering: the first `Integer` parameter is interpreted as the `Cancel` parameter, and the second is the `CloseMode` - the form / COM doesn't care how you called them, it's going to read the `Cancel` value from the first parameter anyway.

You can avoid this problem in the future, by selecting the event from the dropdowns at the top of the code pane:

[image: first select the UserForm interface/event provider from the left dropdown]

Make sure the left-hand dropdown says "UserForm", and then select "QueryClose" from the right-hand dropdown:

[image: then select QueryClose event in the right dropdown]

If there's no handler for it, the VBE will create one *properly formed* for you.

Comment: Thanks for the info, that fixed the problem. 1 - I actually had a bit of error handling that I just deleted out of the bottom of the sub, which is why I had the err.number. I just didn't think it was applicable for this part. I should have gotten rid of that first if though since I got rid of the bottom stuff. The exit subs were in there for the same reason. 2 - I've always done MSG as string, funny that I've been doing it wrong for so long... 3 - I definitely typed it from memory: won't be doing that again... Anyhow, thanks for the very concise and detailed answer! Got my upvote :)

Comment: @JaredBurton Thanks for the checkmark! If you have working VBA code that you'd like peer reviewed, I'd love to see some of it on [codereview.se] =)